# Install HTTP PECL extension on Windows

Tags: php, wamp

I try to add the PECL [php_http](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) extension to my wamp server. I think I do it good :

1. Download DLL from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
2. put php_http.dll in the `ext` folder
3. add : `extension=php_http.dll` in php.ini
4. Restart the services

Nothing happens, the extension is not added.

I wanted to be sure that I was in the right php.ini so I uncommented some extensions and restarted the server... they appear.

No... it is just this one in particular I added myself that is never shown.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you've chosen dll version correctly (i.e. is compiled for your platform).

Comment: the dll is for php5.3 and my wamp is version 2.2 supporting php 5.3

Comment: Check System-type (32-bit or 64).

Comment: got it from this site : http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Comment: it looks like there is no 64-bit version for this one so I got the 32 which is good

Comment: ok what means vc6 and vc9 ... it works with vc9

Comment: some kind of system version ?

Comment: @Marc, there's no need to flood the question with comments, you can actually *edit* the question itself and add further details there. I've already done myself.

Comment: how do I say that your comment helped me ?

Comment: @Marc `VC6` stands for `Visual Studio C++ 6`, `VC9` - `Visual Studio C++ 9` and in given context shows using which dll was compiled. Answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have wamp 2.2 and if you left click the wamp icon, hover over to php->php extensions and make sure there's a checkmark for "php_http" and that will enable pecl as it did for me.

Comment: I cannot find such extension